Powershell filebrowser dialog includes shortcut files despite filter
I run the following powershell script to select .ps1 files :
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$FileBrowser.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp"
$FileBrowser.Filter = "Files ps1(*.ps1)|*.ps1"
[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog() 

Despite the filter, shortcut files are included in the selection.
My folder contains the following files :
a.ps1
cdr.accdb
CDR_RETOURS_70.accdb
MAIL.docx --> word file
MAIL.docx --> .lnk shortcut to the MAIL.docx word file 

The filebrowser dialog offfers :
a.ps1
MAIL.docx (the .lnk shortcut to the MAIL.docx word file)

What did I wrong?
Thank you
I expected to get only
a.ps1

Directories, when they exist, are also shown.

Your only option might be  to set the Hidden attribute, and use ShowhiddenFiles

I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Are you sure your filter is right?

I'm using PowerShell 5.1.19041.4291 on Windows 10 22H2 and the same thing happens to me too. The OpenFileDialog apparently always shows .lnk and .url shortcuts too.

@Theo: except when they are Hidden (and System). see: How to hide files and folder in windows even if "show hidden files" is on

@Luuk : sure setting the hidden attribute may work, but a hidden shortcut is useless;

@Theo : I'm on Windows 11 23 H2 and I agree with you

Shortcut files are "special" windows files handled by the shell - the exact behavior is a bit opaque. As a result, common controls like OpenFileDialog are aware of this behavior, and it cant be easily changed (you might be able to with some inline c#, but that is getting complicated).
As far as i know, the only option related to Lnk files is $FileBrowser.DereferenceLinks = $true - this will cause the OpenFileDialog to return the links destination instead of the .lnk file itself if a lnk file is selected - but it wont prevent the .lnk files from being displayed or selected.
Weirdly, if you create a blank file with a random file extension that is not registered to an application, those lnk files are filtered out. I think your facing inconsistent behavior from Windows itself and i dont think there is much you can do about it from pure PowerShell.

OK, hank you.
As a work around i use a filter with get-childitem and i populate a combobox with the returned files names.
